# Support only portrait orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I need to support only portrait orientation in my app. How can I do it? I have tried adding

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

and

```
 -(BOOL)     shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

But it does't help - the view rotates anyway.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-(BOOL)     shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`should return a BOOL which is `NO`in your case.

Answer (score 2):

This should be:

```
 -(BOOL)     shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 
           || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In XCode 5 (not sure about earlier versions), if you want on support portrait mode only across the whole app, go to Project Settings->General->Deployment info
and uncheck Upside Down, Orientation Left, and Orientation Right.

This is probably the easiest way to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 6, it seems you need to add/override this method too,

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```